Reducing Named Parameters in Native Queries and Simplifying Repository Method Calls
I'm working on a task that requires me to retrieve data using filters. I created a native query. The repository method has only a few named parameters. But, I'm searching for a different approach to reduce the number of arguments I have to send to the repository function so that I can retrieve the values from the corresponding query fields. I am curious to learn and explore different solutions. Appreciate any suggestions!!. any thoughts on this..
Here it is my current state of my code.
@Query(value =testsQuery+
            "AND (" +
            "        CASE " +
            "            WHEN :expertLevel IS NULL THEN true " +
            "            ELSE a.expertLevel = :expertLevel" +
            "        END" +
            "    )" +
            "AND (" +
            "        CASE " +
            "            WHEN :testType IS NULL THEN true " +
            "            ELSE a.testType = :testType" +
            "        END" +
            "    )" +
            "AND (" +
            "        CASE " +
            "            WHEN :technology IS NULL THEN true " +
            "            ELSE t.id = :technology" +
            "        END" +`
            "    )" +
            "AND (" +
            "        CASE " +
            "            WHEN :category IS NULL THEN true " +
            "            ELSE c.id = :category" +
            "        END" +
            "    )" +
            "GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.duration, a.expertLevel, a.testType, c.name, j.name, t.name")
    List<GettestQueryItem> findAlltestsBy(
            @Param("tenantId") Long tenantId,
            @Param("expertLevel") ExpertLevel expertLevel,
            @Param("testType") TestType testType,
            @Param("technology") Long technology,
            @Param("category") Long category);
}

Here TestType and ExperLevel both are enum type values.
I don't want to use Criteria API.

It's generally a bad idea (and a very unmaintainable one) to have page long native queries embedded in your code. In fact, even a one liner native query isn't a good idea -- no syntax checking, cluttered with non standard formatting and escaping, etc. Either use a stored procedure or Querydsl.

Does this answer your question? Dynamic spring data jpa repository query with arbitrary AND clauses
